# Select corresponding column based on columns

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, I try to select a corresponding value based on the greatest value between columns.

Let's take as example table 'prices':

| id | supplier | price1 | quantity1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Microsoft | 8,27 | 1000 |
| 1 | Apple | 10,25 | 2000 |
| 1 | IBM | 12,25 | 3000 |
| 2 | Microsoft | 9,45 | 2000 |
| 2 | Apple | 7,55 | 4000 |
| 2 | IBM | 6,78 | 6000 |

The result I intend to get is:

| id | price_microsoft | price_apple | price_ibm | best price | best price corresponding quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8,27 | 10,25 | 12,25 | 8,27 | 1000 |
| 2 | 9,45 | 7,55 | 6,78 | 6,78 | 4000 |

Is there a possibillity to avoid a self join? Or is the self join just the way to do it?

Comment: can you provide some more context please? If you could share the table structure, and the SQL statement you have tried so far. Also, you would definitely find this easier with a different table structure, so if this is a new table / application, I would suggest altering the table structure to have single price and column fields rather than two of each, if that is at all possible?

Comment: @DaveRix in fact it already is, but let me adjust my example a little. I just thought if the is a way to avoid a self join.

Comment: Will there always be two columns in the two sets?

Comment: @SalmanA yes that I can ensure

Comment: So if there are n rows per id you want the result to magically grow to n+3 columns somehow?

Comment: @SalmanA not magically, the solution you proposed was based on the fixed number of columns n=2 but it could als be fixed number of columns n=3. What I was wondering about is there away to get some kind of index/offset to avoid a self join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8

```
select distinct
 id, 
 sum(case when supplier = 'Microsoft' then price1 else 0 end) over by_id price_ms,
 sum(case when supplier = 'Apple' then price1 else 0 end) over by_id price_apple,
 sum(case when supplier = 'IBM' then price1 else 0 end) over by_id price_ibm,
 min(price1) over by_id best_price,
 first_value(quantity1) over by_id_price best_price_qty
from prices
window 
by_id as (partition by id),
by_id_price as (partition by id order by price1 asc)
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8ccd97adcbe404e85ee9fc119557a88b)

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I came up with which includes the self join. And I believe it's unavoidable the more I think about it.

```
SELECT
   id,
   SUM(CASE WHEN t1.supplier = 'Microsoft' THEN t1.price1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'price_microsoft',
   SUM(CASE WHEN t1.supplier = 'Apple' THEN t1.price1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'price_apple',
   SUM(CASE WHEN t1.supplier = 'IBM' THEN t1.price1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'price_ibm' 
   t2.price1 AS ‘best price’,
   t2.quantity1 AS ‘best price corresponding quantity’
FROM prices 
JOIN
  (SELECT id, MIN(price1), quantity1 FROM prices GROUP BY id) AS t2 
ON t1.id=t2.id GROUP BY id
```

Comment: I think that is going to be the right way to get the data you are after. I was going to suggest the self-join method, but it wouldn't have worked with the original posting of the question.